# How to set up module for Bash project

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA, with Bash Support plug-in, but I don't understand how to properly create the project for this. I created the project as an empty project, but now I need to create a module before I can add any files to the project (right?). However, it wants me to choose a language.

Because this is really just a bash script, it doesn't use any of the available options:

[image: module options]

How should I go about this to properly set this project?

Answer (score 4):

Selecting any of those options should work.

If you have the [BashSupport](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230-bashsupport) plugin, you will get the syntax highlighting on .sh files.

I mix bash scripts in my projects all the time and have several projects that are all shell scripts. Intellij is geared towards Java, so in these projects I still select the language level etc.

Comment: Yes, but if for instance, I select Java, IDEA will also load the libraries for the JVM. Can't we keep the project "clean"?

Comment: You could create "Static web" project. It will be almost empty.